# Importing data from csv to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a repetitive process which includes importing data from different csv files to excel

Current process
Import data manually from data > from text > select the required file > select delimited and my data has headers > select delimiter comma > next > finish > New worksheet

Is there a way to make a vba script/macro which will prompt the user what file they want to import and slect the options which I have selected

Thanks and regards

Comment: Macro recorder should give you a good start :)

Comment: Sounds like a possible job for powerquery. Set it up to load from a folder. Put your source files in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is some code I used some time ago.

`Dirlocal` is the path of the `.csv` file

I would have the data imported in a Worksheet named "ODK"

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strText As String

 ' read utf-8 file to strText variable
 With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Open
    .Type = 1  ' Private Const adTypeBinary = 1
    .LoadFromFile DirLocal
    .Type = 2  ' Private Const adTypeText = 2
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    strText = .ReadText(-1)  ' Private Const adReadAll = -1
End With
' parse strText data to a sheet
Set ws = Worksheets("ODK")
intRow = 1
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each strLine In Split(strText, Chr(10))
    If strLine <> "" Then
        With ws
            .Cells(intRow, 1) = strLine
            .Cells(intRow, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(intRow, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False
        End With

        intRow = intRow + 1
    End If
Next strLine
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ReadUTF8CSVToSheet = ws.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application.getopenfilename to select the desired file to open.
As mentioned in one of the comments, using the macro recorder to get the code to manipulate the data is a good start and you can add it to this code.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim s, wb As Workbook
    s = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select CSV file...")
    If s <> False Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(s)
        MsgBox "Code to Do something here"
        wb.Close False
    Else: MsgBox "Nothing Selected"
    End If



End Sub
```